# Getting syntax error when using a multiline print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using python 3.6.6 on Windows 10.

I'm trying to get this menu working, except I keep getting a syntax error at the `i` in `input`. I've tried have the menu options be a print statement instead while having `option = input()` afterwards, but that also leads to syntax errors.

Heres the menu code -

```
repeat = True
while repeat = True:
    option = input("""Please choose an option:
1) Bubble Sort
2) Merge Sort
3) Binary Search
4) Linear Search
5) Quit
""")

    try:
        option = float(option)
        if option > 5:
            repeat = False
        else:
            if option == 1:
                bubbleSort()
            elif option == 2:
                mergeSort()
            elif option == 3:
                binarySearch()
            elif option == 4:
                linearSearch()
            elif option == 5:
                quit("Now quitting...")
    except ValueError:
        print('Sorry, that is not an available option. Please try again. ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the second `=`:

```
while repeat == True:
```

But you can simplify this to:

```
while repeat:
```

Comment: Or removing `repeat = True` and just using `while True` would work as well since the user is not setting the `repeat` variable to false at any point in the code.

Comment: @DrZoo It's true the code could be simplified further , but OP does do `if option > 5: repeat = False`

Comment: Goddamn it, I knew it'd be something simple. Thanks! ^-^

Comment: Oops I missed that part.

Answer (score 1):

On line 2, you're missing a `=`. You code should be:

```
while repeat == True:
```

not

```
while repeat = True:
```

Additionally, you don't need the `== True` part. Only

```
while repeat:
```

will do.